# Spark Delta table restore to version

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I am trying to restore a delta table to its previous version via spark java , am using local ide .code is as below

```
import io.delta.tables.*; 
DeltaTable deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, <path-to-table>); 
DeltaTable deltaTable = DeltaTable.forName(spark, <table-name>); 
deltaTable.restoreToVersion(0) // restore table to     oldest version
deltaTable.restoreToTimestamp("2019-02-14") // restore to a specific timestamp
```

As per the documentation [databricks doc](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-utility.html#restore-a-delta-table-to-an-earlier-state&language-java) the method given here is not available in delta-core version 0.8.0. The method is also not in the [api docs](https://docs.delta.io/latest/api/java/index.html) .

Is this only available in Datbricks run time?

Currently i have to load with the previous version and rewrite the df using delta.Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Deltalake version 0.8 does not have `restoreToVersion` and `restoreToTimestamp` methods. There is no trace of such methods in open-source deltalake 0.8 as you can check in [delta-lake repository](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/v0.8.0/src/main/scala/io/delta/tables/DeltaTable.scala)

So currently and as far as I know, there is no other method than rewriting from a previous version, as explained in answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57665808/delta-lake-rollback)

###### EDIT

As commented by [boyangeor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4150675/boyangeor), [restoreToVersion](https://docs.delta.io/latest/api/java/io/delta/tables/DeltaTable.html#restoreToVersion-long-) and [restoreToTimestamp](https://docs.delta.io/latest/api/java/io/delta/tables/DeltaTable.html#restoreToTimestamp-java.lang.String-) are now available in DeltaLake from [version 1.2](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/releases/tag/v1.2.0)

Comment: `RESTORE` is now supported in delta1.2: [docs.delta.io/1.2.0](https://docs.delta.io/1.2.0/delta-utility.html#restore-a-delta-table-to-an-earlier-state)

Answer (score 0):

The rollback "restoreVersion" is very much this:

In python

```
delta_table_path = "/tmp/delta-table"
df = spark.read.format("delta").option("versionAsOf", 0).load(delta_table_path)     
df.show()
```

In Java:

```
String delta_table_path = "/tmp/delta-table"
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("delta").option("versionAsOf", 0).load(delta_table_path);
df.show();
```

In Scala:

```
var delta_table_path = "/tmp/delta-table"
val df = spark.read.format("delta").option("versionAsOf", 0).load(delta_table_path)
df.show()
```